# ubuntu 20.04.03 cannot access internet

Tags: networking

[sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWdHW.png) after I installed my ubuntu server, I cannot access the internet. I am able to access it from my network. Any idea what would it be? I installed the basic/default settings.

Thanks

---

pctech@live:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group defaul
                                                                                                                     t qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group de  
                                                                                                                   fault qlen 1000
link/ether 00:50:56:b1:66:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.51.111/22 brd 192.168.51.255 scope global dynamic ens160
valid_lft 604225sec preferred_lft 604225sec
inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb1:6636/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


pctech@live:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

pctech@live:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 24 08:42 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolv

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands:  `ip addr show` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and, finally: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ok. just edited my question. thanks

Comment: Do you mean: `/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: Hi chili555, yes

Answer (score 1):

Please amend your netplan file. First, find out it's exact name:

```
ls /etc/netplan
```

Next, edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/<what_you_found>.yaml
```

Amend it to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing, identation, etc. so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor nano (Ctrl+x followed by Enter).

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Test:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns from both, you're all set.

Comment: I still cannot ping. I tried to paste in the comment how it was spaced but not sure how you spaced it here. i will update the question with a snapshot.

Comment: Your snapshot appears correct. Did you try a reboot?  Are there any clues in the message log? `sudo dmesg | grep ens`

Comment: pctech@live:~$ ls /etc/netplan<br>
00-installer-config.yaml<br>
pctech@live:~$ sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml<br>
pctech@live:~$ sudo netplan generate<br>
pctech@live:~$ sudo netplan apply<br>
pctech@live:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8<br>
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.<br>
<br>
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---<br>
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2036ms<br>

Comment: ok here it is:<br>pctech@live:~$ sudo dmesg | grep ens
[sudo] password for pctech:
[    0.168888] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    1.540115] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 ens160: renamed from eth0
[    1.997093] sd 32:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 61 00 00 00
[    7.173425] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 ens160: intr type 3, mode 0, 3 vectors allocated
[    7.174286] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 ens160: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps

Comment: I think you failed to mention that this is a virtual machine.

Comment: oops. sorry. yes it is a virtual machine

Comment: do i need to install a different version of ubuntu?

Comment: In your VirtualBox setup, you'll want to ensure your network adapter is set to "Bridged." Is it?

Comment: i am using vmware esxi. could not find any option to make the network as bridge. i will try to open a ticket with vmware and ask them if there is a particular options i need to set to make this work. will update this once i got it to work